# How to prevent attribute from being set again if one has already been set preiously?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Javascript so I apologize in advance if I'm using the wrong terminology or this is very simple to do.

I'm creating a video background player that uses Javascript to set the value of a src of a video tag so that it only loads the video file above a certain specified browser window width as using `@media (min-width)` with `display: none;` was still triggering the video src to load. If the browser window is below this resolution and then is resized to be at or above this certain specified width, the video src should have its value set.

An issue I ran into is that the Javascript onResize event was triggering the entire time the page was resizing and so the background video was restarted repeatedly. So I found this [code](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/firing-resize-event-only-once-when-resizing-is-finished/) and used it to give it a delay so that it would only set the value of the video src after resizing was done and not the whole time. Now, when the browser window is resized from below this certain specified width to above it the video loads. But, if I resize it again, the video src is set again causing a blink (while it shows the fallback background image behind it) and the video restarts from the beginning. As this will run a looping video, it's easy to see this restart. How do I prevent the video from restarting if it's already been loaded? aka. How do I prevent the video src from being set if it's already been set?

I do not know enough about Javascript to know what to try next. The code I currently have has been stitched together from multiple sources.

```
// ON LOAD    

window.onload = function() {

    if (window.innerWidth >= 769) { // This only loads the video at or above this resolution. Make sure it matches "Desktop - load video with jpg fallback"

        document.querySelector("video.video-bg-player").src = "video_file.webm"; // WEBM video url (webm appears to be the best cross-browser file) 

    } 

};

// AFTER RESIZE   

var resizeId;
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeId);
    resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

function doneResizing(){

    if (window.innerWidth >= 769) { // This only loads the video at or above this resolution. Make sure it matches "Desktop - load video with jpg fallback"

        document.querySelector("video.video-bg-player").src = "video_file.webm"; // WEBM video url (webm appears to be the best cross-browser file) 

    } 

}
```

Currently resizing the window after the video has already loaded causes the video to pause and restart (due to the video src being set again). If the video src has already been set, then it shouldn't be set again.

Comment: A note to future finders, there is only a single video filename "video_file.webm". A previous version of my question accidentally had two filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to achieve it by storing the query in a variable and check if the `src` of that variable is empty.

for example:

```
// ON LOAD    
var element;
window.onload = function() {

    if (window.innerWidth >= 769 && !element) { // This only loads the video at or above this resolution. Make sure it matches "Desktop - load video with jpg fallback"

        element = document.querySelector("video.video-bg-player");

        if (element.src != "video_file.webm")
           element.src = "video_file.webm"; // WEBM video url (webm appears to be the best cross-browser file) 

    } 

};

// AFTER RESIZE   

var resizeId;
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeId);
    resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

function doneResizing(){

    if (window.innerWidth >= 769 && !element) { // This only loads the video at or above this resolution. Make sure it matches "Desktop - load video with jpg fallback"

        element = document.querySelector("video.video-bg-player");

        if (element.src != "video_file.webm")
            element.src = "beer_bg3.webm"; // WEBM video url (webm appears to be the best cross-browser file) 

    } 

}
```

I did not test the code, but that's what I think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ON LOAD    

window.onload = function() {

    if (window.innerWidth >= 769) { // This only loads the video at or above this resolution. Make sure it matches "Desktop - load video with jpg fallback"

        document.querySelector("video.video-bg-player").src = "video_file.webm"; // WEBM video url (webm appears to be the best cross-browser file) 

    } 

};

// AFTER RESIZE   

var resizeId;
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeId);
    resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

function doneResizing(){

    if (window.innerWidth >= 769) { // This only loads the video at or above this resolution. Make sure it matches "Desktop - load video with jpg fallback"

        var el = document.querySelector("video.video-bg-player");
        if (el.src != "beer_bg3.webm")
            el.src = "beer_bg3.webm"; // WEBM video url (webm appears to be the best cross-browser file) 

    } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the window is loaded above 769px width, the video loads and the resizing does indeed prevent the src from reloading. Thank you! However, if the window is loaded below the 769px width, the video doesn't load (as it should), but when it is resized larger than the 769px width, then the video doesn't load. When using inspect on the code and resizing I see that the "src" does indeed not change. Initially, I had src omitted, but thought that that's what might be causing the issue so I added it and it still doesn't load the video. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Yes. The video source isn't set upon load at the smaller width.